# Implementing a hash table in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, hashtable

I'm having trouble to implement a simple list in C, the problem is the connection of the items via pointers.
The following piece of code is a snippet from a hashtable, which is supposed to store items with the same index in a list to avoid collisions.

```
typedef struct dictEntry {
    void *key;
    void *value;
    struct dictEntry *next;
} dictEntry;

typedef struct dict {
    dictEntry **table;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long used;
} dict;

void dictAdd(dict *d, void *key, void *value) {
    int index = hash(key) & d->size;
    dictEntry *entry;

    entry = malloc(sizeof(entry));

    entry->key   = key;
    entry->value = value;
    entry->next  = 0;

    if (d->table[index]) {
        /* this is does not work */
        dictEntry *next;
        next = d->table[index];

        while (next) {
            next = next->next;
        }

        next = entry;
    } else {
        d->table[index] = entry;
        d->used++;
    }
}
```

My thinking was to iterate through every element of the list (`next->next`) and assign the pointer of `entry` to the last element (`next = entry;`).
After a few days of rewriting and moving parts of the code around, I still can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: `next = entry;`.. setting a local variable won't do anything...

Comment: I have got linked lists wrong so many times in C that I always use a library. If this isn't homework I suggest you do too!

Comment: It's no homework, just learning some C with basic stuff like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to implement the linked list first.

Here's how I would implement the addition to the end (I've modified your code where you just overwrite the temporary "next" variable without modifying the list itself):

```
if (d->table[index]) {
    /* this should work*/
    dictEntry *next;
    dictEntry *prev = NULL;
    next = d->table[index];

    while (next) {
        prev = next;
        next = next->next;
    }

    // yes, add new entry as the "next" pointer to the "last" item
    prev->next = entry;
} else {
```

....

Answer (score 1):

```
entry = malloc(sizeof(entry));
```

should be:

```
entry = malloc(sizeof *entry);
```

Also dictAdd is overly complex. Using a pointer-to-pointer will help in this case:

```
void dictAdd(dict *d, void *key, void *value) {
    unsigned index;
    dictEntry **pp;

    index = hash(key) % d->size;
    if (!d->table[index]) d->used++;

    for (pp = &d->table[index]; *pp; pp = &(*pp)->next) {;}

    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
     /* Omitted : handle ((*pp) == NULL) malloc failure here */
    (*pp)->key   = key;
    (*pp)->value = value;
    (*pp)->next  = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Your `sizeof` suggestion is more confusing than it needs to be. Did you really have to remove the parenthesis? It obfuscates the far more important fact that you added the asterisk.

Comment: On the contrary: There are *two* syntactic forms of sizeof: `sizeof expr)` and  `sizeof(type)` The absence of `()`stipulates the fact that the first one is *intended*. [ `sizeof(expr)` is also valid because of `expr := '( expr')` . ]

Comment: Ah, I see what you were trying to do there, but wouldn't it be best to write `sizeof(dictEntry)`? That seems much more straightforward and readable to me.

Comment: *No!!* because that would force you to duplicate the type. eg: `*pp= malloc(sizeof (DictHeader));` would go unnoticed. So, it is better to stick to the "add one asterix" rule. (you'll get used to it)

Comment: Oh, right. What about `sizeof(entry[0])`? Any preference regarding that syntax?

Comment: It can be overly confusing (and when possible you should always avoid excessive `()`, IMHO) . The "add one asterix" rule is never confusing (except maybe in initializers, where the LHS also carries an extra asterix)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your while loop. You are going until `next` becomes zero, but you really want the last entry that has the next pointer being zero. Fix that and it should be closer.